# How to install m2crypto for Salt on Windows?

Tags: windows, pip, salt-stack, m2crypto

I compiled the newest `m2crypto` for some x509 action, got a `M2Crypto-0.38.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl` out of it and installed this via `pip`.

Now I have a lot of files under `C:\salt\bin\Lib\site-packages\M2Crypto\` like `m2crypto.py` and `x509.py`. However, my state which works under Linux gives me still the debug output:

> Reason: 'x509' __virtual__ returned False: Could not load x509 state: m2crypto unavailable

I copied all files from `C:\salt\bin\Lib\site-packages\M2Crypto\` to
`C:\salt\bin\Lib\site-packages\salt-3003.3-py3.7.egg\salt\modules` without overwrite, but that didn't help.

I restarted the salt-minion service.

What am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to ensure python libraries are in the correct place for Salt is to use the [`pip.installed` state](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.pip_state.html):

```yaml
install m2crypto:
  pip.installed:
    - name: path/to/M2Crypto-0.38.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
    - reload_modules: true
```

There seems to be pre-built packages [available on pypi](https://pypi.org/project/M2CryptoWin64/), which may be easier:

```yaml
install m2crypto:
  pip.installed:
    - name: M2CryptoWin64
    - reload_modules: true
```

Your `x509` states should then require `install m2crypto`.

Inside `...\salt\modules` is very wrong, and you should try to undo that (or reinstall salt).

Comment: Hello, thanks for the package hint, i already have confirmed that the m2crypto v 0.21 from 2014 there is much too old. Also, if i list packages via pip, my M2crypto shows up. How would i check which Modules Salt would see, possibly with the salt state for pip ? Would be nice to know, thanks

Comment: There are two grains, `pythonexecutable` and `pythonpath`. Something like `<pythonexecutable> -m pip list` should show all the packages.

Comment: so, a "pip list" gives me my M2crypto back, but a "salt-call sys.list_modules" not (it has pip tho) , hope you can point me to howto "connect" it ?

Comment: `list_modules` lists salt modules, not python packages. Did you do `pip list`, or did you do the command I said?

Comment: python.exe -m pip list   shows M2crypto, 
i got alot of debug logs with Modules like SMIME , DH, RC4 and even UTIL, THREADING, i wonder if its like normal to miss those, here is a small excerpt:            ImportError: DLL load failed: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.
[DEBUG   ] Override  __pillar__: <module 'salt.loaded.int.module.virtualenv_mod' from 'C:\\salt\\bin\\lib\\site-packages\\salt-3003.3-py3.7.egg\\salt\\modules\\virtualenv_mod.py'>
[DEBUG   ] Could not LazyLoad x509.get_pem_entry: 'x509' __virtual__ returned False: Could not load x509 module, m2crypto unavailable

Comment: @germansche Are you saying that `salt grains.get pythonexecutable` returns only `python.exe`? "DLL load failed" means you probably didn't build it correctly, but it is in the right place.